# Javascript Array granulation

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash, underscore.js

We have an Array of length ~40K and those are failed data to sync up with the external system. The external system expects the data in the form of an Array of subarrays based on the id and sort by created date asc from the main array itself. Each `id` may have multiple failures in the source system and `"data":{}` is distinct in each record of the main array.

Is there any library available to achieve the result efficiently? Coz, this has to run daily.

```
let customerData = [
{
    "id": 1,
    "data": {},
    "createdDate": ""
},
{
    "id": 1,
    "data": {},
    "createdDate": ""
},
{
    "id": 1,
    "data": {},
    "createdDate": ""
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "data": {},
    "createdDate": ""
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "data": {},
    "createdDate": ""
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "data": {},
    "createdDate": ""
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "data": {},
    "createdDate": ""
},
{
    "id": 4,
    "data": {},
    "createdDate": ""
},
{
    "id": 4,
    "data": {},
    "createdDate": ""
}
];
```

And the expected data should be like below to be sent to the external system.

```
let modifiedData = [
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "data": {},
        "createdDate": ""
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "data": {},
        "createdDate": ""
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "data": {},
        "createdDate": ""
    }
],
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "data": {},
        "createdDate": ""
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "data": {},
        "createdDate": ""
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "data": {},
        "createdDate": ""
    }
],
[
    {
        "id": 3,
        "data": {},
        "createdDate": ""
    }
],
[
    {
        "id": 4,
        "data": {},
        "createdDate": ""
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "data": {},
        "createdDate": ""
    }
]
]
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use the lodash function [_.groupBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#groupBy) for this purpose. We group by id, then use [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to get the result as an array of arrays:

```js
const customerData = [ { "id": 1, "data": {}, "createdDate": "" }, { "id": 1, "data": {}, "createdDate": "" }, { "id": 1, "data": {}, "createdDate": "" }, { "id": 2, "data": {}, "createdDate": "" }, { "id": 2, "data": {}, "createdDate": "" }, { "id": 2, "data": {}, "createdDate": "" }, { "id": 3, "data": {}, "createdDate": "" }, { "id": 4, "data": {}, "createdDate": "" }, { "id": 4, "data": {}, "createdDate": "" } ];

const result = Object.values( _.groupBy(customerData, 'id'));
console.log("Result:", result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-90vH1Z83AJY9DmlWa8WkjkV79yfS2n2Oxhsi2dZbIv0nC4E6m5AbH8Nh156kkM7JePmqD6tcZsfad1ueoaovww==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

We can also do this with vanilla JavaScript using [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), creating a map keyed on `id`, then using [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) again.

```js
const customerData = [ { "id": 1, "data": {}, "createdDate": "" }, { "id": 1, "data": {}, "createdDate": "" }, { "id": 1, "data": {}, "createdDate": "" }, { "id": 2, "data": {}, "createdDate": "" }, { "id": 2, "data": {}, "createdDate": "" }, { "id": 2, "data": {}, "createdDate": "" }, { "id": 3, "data": {}, "createdDate": "" }, { "id": 4, "data": {}, "createdDate": "" }, { "id": 4, "data": {}, "createdDate": "" } ];

const result = Object.values(customerData.reduce((acc, curr) => { 
    if (!acc[curr.id]) acc[curr.id] = [];
    acc[curr.id].push(curr);
    return acc;
}, {}))

console.log("Result:", result)
```

Comment: The same code also works with Underscore, unmodified.